# C# Iterate through different instances of Chrome and click button

Tags: c#, windows, forms, console-application

I'm working on a project, i need to iterate through multiple instances of google chrome (not tabs) and simulate a user clicking on a button.

All instances will be preloaded with the same page, so im thinking iterate through the different instances and click on a pre defined x,y coordinate.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Use UI Automation, no fake clicking with messages

Comment: Had a look at Selenium, but it looks like, it has to open the browsers itself, it cant attach to manually loaded instances. Any ideas ?